Printing RFID with zebra zd500r in a web project
I have a react project and I want to write rfid with zebra zd500r. I connect my printer via USB. I tried two ways to print, 1st way I tried printing using zebra's browserprint sdk. My function in the browser printer SDK was basically similar to this.
const zpl = `^XA^FO50,50^ADN,36,20^FDHello Zebra^FS^XZ`;

window.BrowserPrint.getDefaultDevice(
  "printer",
  (device) => {
    if (device) {
      console.log("Seçilen Yazıcı:", device);

      device.send(
        zpl,
        (response) => {
          console.log("Yazdırma Başarılı:", response);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error("Yazdırma Hatası:", error);
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.error("Varsayılan yazıcı bulunamadı.");
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    console.error("Yazıcı alınırken hata:", error);
  }
);

Even though the status was 200, there was no movement on the printer either.
The second way was to write it through a node.js application. Even though the printer worked, I only got void as output. Code:
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const usb = require("usb");

const app = express();
const port = 5001;

// Yazıcı bilgileri (Vendor ve Product ID)
const VENDOR_ID = 2655; // Zebra'nın Vendor ID'si
const PRODUCT_ID = 221; // Yazıcınızın Product ID'si

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Yazıcı bağlantısını kontrol etme endpoint'i
app.get("/check-connection", (req, res) => {
  const printer = usb.findByIds(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);

  if (!printer) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Printer not found" });
  }

  res.status(200).json({ message: "Printer is connected via USB!" });
});

// RFID yazma endpoint'i
app.post("/write-rfid", (req, res) => {
  const { rfidData } = req.body;

  if (!rfidData) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "RFID data is required!" });
  }

  const zplCommand = `
        ^XA
        ^RS8             
        ^RFW,H           
        ^FD1234567890^FS
        ^XZ
    `;

  const printer = usb.findByIds(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);

  if (!printer) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Printer not found" });
  }

  try {
    printer.open();

    const iface = printer.interfaces[0];
    iface.claim();

    const outEndpoint = iface.endpoints.find((ep) => ep.direction === "out");
    if (!outEndpoint) {
      throw new Error("No valid output endpoint found");
    }

    outEndpoint.transfer(Buffer.from(zplCommand), (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error sending data:", err);
        res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to send data to printer" });
      } else {
        console.log("ZPL Command Sent Successfully");
        res.status(200).json({ message: "RFID data written successfully!" });
      }
      printer.close();
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error:", err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to write RFID data" });
  }
});

app.get('/printer-status', (req, res) => {
    const printer = usb.findByIds(VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);

    if (!printer) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Printer not found' });
    }

    try {
        printer.open();
        const iface = printer.interfaces[0];
        iface.claim();

        const outEndpoint = iface.endpoints.find((ep) => ep.direction === 'out');
        const inEndpoint = iface.endpoints.find((ep) => ep.direction === 'in');

        if (!outEndpoint || !inEndpoint) {
            throw new Error('No valid endpoints found');
        }

        // `~HS` komutunu gönder
        const statusCommand = '~HS';
        outEndpoint.transfer(Buffer.from(statusCommand), (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error sending command:', err);
                res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send status command' });
                return;
            }

            // Gelen yanıtı oku
            inEndpoint.transfer(1024, (error, data) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error('Error receiving data:', error);
                    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to receive status data' });
                } else {
                    console.log('Printer Status:', data.toString());
                    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Printer status retrieved', status: data.toString() });
                }
                printer.close();
            });
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err.message);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to retrieve printer status' });
    }
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Zebra USB Printer API running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


I tried this on mac and windows computers. Since I don't know exactly what I should do, I don't know if these are the best ways to follow.

I see qz-tray was tagged here, but there's no examples of the qz-tray library being used.  That said, the question appears to be two-fold: 1. Why is nothing printing when using the BrowserPrint API.  2. Why is the ZPL command ^RFW,H^FD<DATA>^FS not working as expected.  Neither endpoints (neither /check-connection or /write-rfid) are obvious to the reader.  If you do wish to use qz-tray, the easiest way is to use forceRaw: true in the API.  Our raw examples do have ZPL but won't provide a status either; You should  clarify your question to a particular technology.
